# If statement works but when I add else nothing works

Tags: jquery

I'm making password hide/show toggle with jQuery, when I add two buttons one for show and the other one for hide everything works perfectly but i want to toggle here's the code

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.1').on('click',function(){
        var pass = $('.password');
        if(pass.attr('type','password')){
            pass.attr('type','text');
        }
        else{
            pass.attr('type','password');
        }
    })
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <h1>Form</h1>
    Enter your login <input class="login">
    Enter password here <input class="password" type="password">
    <button class="1">Show password</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `if(pass.attr('type','password')){` should be `if(pass.attr('type') === 'password'){`

Comment: `pass.attr('type','password')` ***sets*** the `type` attribute on the selected element to `password`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct you `if()` condition like below:

```
if(pass.attr('type') ==='password')){
```

I will try to do it like below:

```js
function togglePassword(obj) {
  var x = document.getElementById("password");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
    $(obj).html('Hide Password');
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
    $(obj).html('Show Password');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <h1>Form</h1>
  Enter your login <input class="login"><br>
  <!-- converted  class to id to make it unique -->
  Enter password here <input id="password" type="password"><br>
  <button onclick="togglePassword(this)">Show Password</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.1').on('click',function(){
        var current_type = $('.password').attr('type');
        if(current_type == 'password'){
            $('.password').attr('type','text');
        }
        else{
            $('.password').attr('type','password');
        }
    });
})
```